# osgi dependency injection between services

Tags: service, osgi, code-injection, between

I just started playing around with OSGi services and have the following situation. I have a project which contains 2 services. Service A requires Service B, so I tried to inject the dependent service using

```
@Inject
private ServiceB svc;
```

but the framework wont inject. If I setup the following two methods in Service A
and set these methods as "bind / undbind" in my OSGi componentA.xml the framework calls
these methods and I can use Service B in Service A.

```
public synchronized void bind(IServiceB service)
{
  this.svc = service;
}

public synchronized void unbind(IServiceB service)
{
  if (this.svc == service)
  {
    this.svc = null;
  }
}
```

The question is, why does it not work with @Inject ? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm quite new to this whole topic. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Declarative Services, which does not support field injection or the JSR-330 annotations. Field injection has limited utility in OSGi, where services may be injected **or "un-injected"** at any time. Method injection is more generally useful because it gives you an opportunity to do something when this happens.

However I do urge you to use the annotations for Declarative Services. This will save you from having to write the component.xml by hand.

Comment: Hello Neil and thanks for the answer. I didn't mentioned it but you are of course right, I'm using DS. Can you explain a little further what you mean with "annotations for DS" ? What I did so far is generate a component.xml and setup the requiremed informations using the eclipse editor (just like the manifest editor, only a few clicks for setting service interface an implementation class). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: So again some guesswork suggests you are using Eclipse PDE (Plugin Development Environment)? Ouch ouch ouch. That's going to cause you a lot of pain down the road. In PDE you essentially can't generate *anything* and have to do it all by hand. Take a look at the bndtools tutorial (http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html) which should give an idea about the annotations specifically, and in general how a proper tool can make your life much easier.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse JEE Edition thats right. Thanks for the bndtools hint, I'll investigate that further! At first I thought these annotations come "out-of-the-box" by OSGi. I think the question is made sufficiently clear and thank you again for that!

Comment: Great. BTW Bndtools can be installed into Eclipse JEE edition without any problem, assuming you are using Eclipse 3.7 or higher.

Comment: There are some tools to process annotations in the PDE environment, like the one at http://www.wuetherich.com, but there are downsides (like the need for the annotations package import in the manifest). If you are just beginning with OSGi/eClipse and DS you are probably best off to start with bndtools.